# Guest Vs User for Powershell commands execution

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Confused regarding "guest" and "user" type in Azure .

Although i am given Global Admin role but my user type is Guest. So do i have right to execute powershell cmdlets . Because when i fire "Connect-AzureRmAccount" it shows only Account and Environment no azure subscription or id.

Connect-AzureRmAccount

Account          : MyEmail
SubscriptionName : 
SubscriptionId   : 
TenantId         : 
Environment      : AzureCloud

I want to execute powershell cmdlets can i do it as guest . My company has csp account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Make sure your account has an [RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) in the subscription, then use the command as below. If not, you need to add your account to the subscription firstly, ask the `Owner` of the subscription to navigate to the subscription in the portal > `Access control (IAM)` > Click `Add` > `Add role assignment` > add your account as a role(e.g. `Owner`, `Contributor`), more details see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "<tenant id>" -Subscription "<subscription id>"
```

[image]

[image]

**Note** : In my sample I use the new `Az` command `Connect-AzAccount`, the old `Connect-AzureRmAccount` is also the same.

Comment: this helped now i am getting subscription name and id in account object . But when i try to set default subscription i am getting below error ._Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name Microsoft Azure doesn't exist_. below are command i am using     `$account = Connect-AzureRmAccount -Tenant "My Tenant Id” -Subscription “My Subscription Id"

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $account.Context.Subscription.Name -Default`

Comment: @GauravMoolani You need to use `Set-AzureRmContext -Subscription xxx`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/set-azurermcontext?view=azurermps-6.13.0). The `Select-AzureSubscription` is for ASM not ARM.

Answer (score 0):

guest is user from other directory and user is user from same directory.
For example your ad domain is **xyz.onmicrosoft.com** then **user1@onmicrsoft.com** will be user and **user2@anything.com** will be guest user

Comment: The intention of my question is can i execute Azure powershell cmdlets even if i am a guest user ?

Comment: Yes...only some of the commands are restricted like creating automation run as account